# How to inherit sparsebundle on macOS Server Time Machine service?

Tags: backup, time-machine, osx-server, time-capsule, migration

I am using macOS Server's Time Machine service to centralize backups for my mac workstations/laptops. One of the laptops hasn't been backed-up since upgrading to a new MacBook Pro (using Migration Assistant) 6 months ago. I'm now connecting the laptop Time Machine to the server, but instead of using the old backups with the same name, it's creating new ones with a "1" at the end of the name (e.g. `MacBook Pro 1` when the name of the existing backup and mac is `MacBook Pro`).

How do I force Time Machine to use the existing backups so that we may keep all the backup history?

For what it's worth, I believe the macOS Server Time Machine service is no more than a SMB share from the laptop's perspective.

I have seen posts on how to do inherit a Time Machine backup on a locally attached drive, but I'm not sure how to do this on a remote sparsebundle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it turns out, it is super easy with a single Terminal command.

First, you need to mount the Time Machine share using Finder. Just browse to the server, then to the share so that it mounts. I mounted with Admin privileges since Admin owns the the Time Machine sparsebundle.

Then, you open Terminal and run this command:

```
sudo tmutil inheritbackup "/path/to/backup.sparsebundle"
```

For example, mine would be:

```
sudo tmutil inheritbackup /Volumes/Time\ Machine/MacBook\ Pro.sparesebundle
```

If your prefer to use quotes intead of the space escape, you should be able to do:

```
sudo tmutil inheritbackup "/Volumes/Time Machine/MacBook Pro.sparesebundle"
```

You will need to enter your Admin password, and that should do it.

I rebooted after this, then selected the backup share in Time Machine and now it's using the existing sparsebundle instead of creating a new one.

Comment: When I run the 'inheritbackup' command, I get the following error message:

Usage: tmutil inheritbackup machine_directory
       tmutil inheritbackup sparse_bundle
/Volumes/Ben's Time Machine/Backups.backupdb: Invalid target

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Also, is there a confirmation message or anything that should appear when the inheritbackup command runs successfully?

Comment: Perhaps `/Volumes/Ben's Time Machine/Backups.backupdb` is not properly formatted/escaped. Did you include the double-quotes around it?

Comment: Hmmm, I might not have. When I left Terminal and returned to Time Machine, however, it was happy to start backing up again inside the same "Backups.backupdb" folder as before I did a clean reinstall of everything. Does that mean that the inheritbackup command worked? The backup was quite large (150GB+).